# Add default collation to existing mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a default collation to my mongodb collections. It's simple to create a new collection with a collation:

```
db.createCollection(name, {collation:{locale:"en",strength:1}})
```

Unfortunately I looked through the docs and didn't see any `db.updateCollection` function.  How am I supposed to add a collation without destroying and recreating all my documents in a new collection?

Comment: That doesn't do what I am looking for.  It updates all documents in the collection that match the query using the specified collation.  What I want to do is set the default collation for the collection that will be used all the time by default.

Comment: MongoDb developers are working on this feature. [See](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-35314).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [collation](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/collation/collation.rst) specifications,

> After the initial release of server version 3.4, many users will want
>   to apply Collations to all operations on an existing collection. Such
>   users will have to supply the Collation option to each operation
>   explicitly; however, eventually the majority of users wishing to use
>   Collations on all operations on a collection will create a collection
>   with a server-side default. We chose to favor user verbosity right now
>   over abstracting the feature for short-term gains.

So you know its not a option just yet.

Comment: Good find.  Gee, so strange that you can't do this!  Oh well good thing I'm in beta so I can recreate the collections easily!

Answer (score 10):

There's one other option that works for my production needs: Execute `mongodump` on a collection

```
mongodump --host hostname --port 32017 --username usr --password pwd --out c:\backup --db my_database --collection my_collection
```

That will generate two files and one of them named `my_collection.metadata.json`. Open this file and modify `options` property according to MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#collation).

```
{
    "options": {
        "collation": {
            "locale": "en",
            "strength": 1
        }       
    }
    ...
}
```

And then restore using `mongorestore`

```
mongorestore --host hostname --port 32017 --username usr --password pwd --db contactstore c:\backup\my_database --drop
```

From then on, any index you create will use that specific collation by default. Unfortunately, this requires a downtime window, so make sure you get one.

Comment: Production needs? Really?

Comment: Yes, it happened once, when collation change was needed due to case sensitivity rules changes.

Comment: This happens in production mode for me, too. In our case, we support "sorting" in a later version of our product. So we need to add "collation" now, which wasn't required in previous versions. Hope export/import will work. I'll give a +1 in that case. Thx! Just one remark - the library we use doesn't support collation to be added to queries, so that's not an option....

Comment: This is the best solution I have found so far, but it doesn't work with my unique field indexes. I ended up dropping every documents and letting mongoose create a new collection from scratch, but this is not production-friendly.