# How can i change mongodb collation for all existing collections and new collections

Tags: mongodb, sorting, collation

I want to fix string sorting error for Turkish character in mongodb.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682160/add-default-collation-to-existing-mongodb-collection/51976344#51976344) and this worked for one collection via backup and restore.

But I have lots of tables for backup, edit and restore for each collection. I want to do this for all existing collections and new collections. And i want do this without backup and restore process, because my db is live db and i afraid of loss any new data.

How can i change mongodb collation for all existing collections and new collections, without backup, edit and restore?

Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840147/how-to-view-or-modify-collation-options-set-on-a-mongodb-collection. You have to recreate the collections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view or modify collation options set on a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840147/how-to-view-or-modify-collation-options-set-on-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: I have already read the things you mentioned. :)

I was wondering if there was any solution other than backup-restore, but then I realized that there is no other way to change it.

It says that such a method is not deliberately given, but I will mark my question as unanswered for anyone who finds a solution in the future.

Thank you.